# Create "tagged" Json Object, instead of just properties

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm having some problems when i try to deserialize my object into a json string.

I'm getting the following object:

```
{
    "idUser": 1,
    "name": "2",
    ...
}
```

But I want to achieve this object:

```
{
    "user": {
        "idUser": 1,
        "name": "2",
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm serializing my object using this code:

```
public static String deserializeUser(User user){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String json = "";
    try {
        json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

I'm using the api `com.fasterxml.jackson`

And here goes my User class:

```
public class User {
    public long idUser;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String phoneNumber;
    @JsonProperty("cpf")
    public String CPF;
    public String password;
    public boolean active;
    private String facebookPictureUrl;
    private String cameraTakenPhotoBase64;
    private String facebookUserId;

... (constructor and getters/setters)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're serializing an instance of User. The intended JSON matches a map with a user property. So you could achieve it with:

```
Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<String, User>();
userMap.put("user", user);
String json = "";

try {
    json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userMap);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's actually worked here, but there is no way to do it just mapping my user object with some kind of annotation, or that's the only way?

Comment: You could take a look at the serialization features of objectMapper. But, even assuming that there were such an option, how would you deserialize such an object? (because the JSON could be rightfully modified outside your application, I suppose...). I think it's a good idea to either use a map or a custom wrapper class.